# Web Api 2 multiple image upload with jquery or angularjs

Tags: jquery, angularjs, file-upload, asp.net-web-api2, image-upload

I am developing a RESTFUL app using Asp.Net Web Api 2 and Angularjs. I have never done image upload the way I am planning to do and I would appreciate if someone could educate me a little bit, giving me examples or at least an article to start with.

What exactly I want to do is the following:
1. being able to upload multiple images at ones, with their preview appearing on the browser before the whole record is saved in the database.
2. I want the pictures to be stored on the disk directly, but their path should be saved in the database as a string.

I need help for both server side and client side development of it. On the client side, any Angularjs or JQuery library is acceptable.

Answer (score 2):

Hi you need to create a Multipart Formatter to support multiple files upload. [Example here](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/652633/ASP-NET-WebApi-MultipartDataMediaFormatter)

In the example they have a e2e example, writing the images on the disk. You just need to adapt to write the fileUrl in the DB.

I never uploaded images with AngularJs but this [library](http://flowjs.github.io/ng-flow/) looks great.

**edit:** Here is a example of a Multipart Request, it's necessary to define a boundary to separate the images. Attention the last boundary should have a prefix -- to mark the end of the request.

```
POST http://yourendpoint/api/images HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=--YourBoundary

----YourBoundary
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="image1"; filename="image1.gif"
Content-Type: image/gif

ImageBytes...asodnaoisdaisndaosind
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="image2"; filename="image2.png"
Content-Type: image/png

ImageBytes...asodnaoisdaisndaosind
----YourBoundary
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="image3"; filename="image3.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpg

ImageBytes...asodnaoisdaisndaosind
----YourBoundary--
```